# HAL_Delay command not working on STM32 - Nucleo-L

Tags: assembly, stm32, nucleo, cmsis

in our Computer Science class, we are learning to use the STEM32 - Nucleo-L controller, to code assembler. I'm a bit further than the rest of the class, so my teacher tasked me to experiment with the "HAL_Delay" command, since he ran into some problems, trying to use the command.

I found out, that the command usually works fine, except if the registers R2 or/and R3 are use for other stuff. I also found out, that the "wait_ms" command works perfectly fine, so should we just use that command or has anyone got a solution. It would also be very usefull, if someone knew the exact location of the subprogram "HAL_Dealy" in the code.

```
.syntax unified
.equ L152,1
.include "../Core/src/regs.s"
.global mainasm
mainasm:


main:
    bl      startup
    ldr     R1,=GPIOA
    ldr     R2,=GPIOC

    gruenwechsel:  //Wechsel von Rot auf Grün
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR] //Ampel auf rot setzen
        mov     R0,#0b1
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#500
        bl      wait_ms     //500ms Warten
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#0b101   //Rote und Grüne LED geichzeitig an
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#500     //500ms Warten
        bl      wait_ms
        b       Gruen       //Ampel auf Grün setzen

    Gruen:      //Grüner Loop
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#0b10000 //Ampel auf Grün
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        ldr     R0,[R1,IDR]
        tst     R0,Bit10    //Schauen ob PA10 gedrueckt ist
        bne     rotwechsel  //Falls ja, in rotwechsel springen
        b       Gruen


    rotwechsel:
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#0b00100 //Grüne und Gelbe LED Gleichzeitig an
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#1000    //Warte 1 Sekunde
        bl      wait_ms
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#0b00001 //Rote LED an
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        b       Rot

    Rot:                    //Roter Loop
        ldr     R0,[R2,ODR]
        mov     R0,#0b000001 //LED Rot an
        strb    R0,[R2,ODR]
        ldr     R0,[R1,IDR]
        tst     R0,Bit10 //Schauen ob PA10 gedrückt ist, falls ja, in Grünwechsel springen
        bne     gruenwechsel
        b       Rot


.end
```

Thats my code. If I change the "wait_ms" lines to "HAL_Delay" the code compiles without errors and also loads on to the chip, but it won't do anything, when i press the buttons.

Comment: HAL_Delay() relies on systick which works on interrupt. So if you don't enable interrupt this will not work. Now if R2 or R3 is used then why the HAL_Delay doesn"t work, it needs more understanding on the chip you are using

Comment: @brushtakopo The chip I am using is the STM32 - Nucleo - L 152RE